# Scala string pattern match regex a star multiple findallin

Tags: regex, scala

I want to parse this string: `"er1r2r3"` with: `"""(e|w|n|s)(r[1-3])*""".r`

```
  val SideR = """(e|w|n|s)""".r

  val PieceR = """(r)([1-3])""".r

  def parseSidedPieces(str: String): (Char, List[Char]) = {
    val side = str(0) match {
      case SideR(s) => s
    }

    val pieces = parsePieces(str.tail)

    (side, pieces)
  }

  def parsePieces(str: String): List[Char] = {
    PieceR.findAllIn(str).toList map {
      case PieceR(c, n) => n
    }
  }
```

But this throws on empty string `""` because `str(0)`.

Fix this, regex only.

Comment: You must use `(e|w|n|s|r[1-3])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be fixed 'regexes only' (whatever that is supposed to mean), because the code fails before the first regex is used.

It fails because you call `apply(index: Int)` on an empty `String`. So, either you do an `isEmpty` check before calling `str(0)` or even `parseSidedPieces`, or you change the code and match the whole `String`:

```
val PieceR = """(r)([1-3])""".r
val CombinedR = "(e|w|n|s)((?:r[1-3])*)".r

def parseSidedPieces(str: String): (Char, List[Char]) = {
  str match {
    case CombinedR(side, pieces) =>
      (side(0), parsePieces(pieces))
    case "" => 
      // hmm, what kind of tuple would be a good return value here? maybe:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unexpected input: $str")
    case _ =>
      // handle unmatched strings however you like, I'd do:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Unexpected input: $str")
  }
}

def parsePieces(str: String): List[Char] = {
  PieceR.findAllIn(str).toList map {
    case PieceR(c, n) => n(0)
  }
}

parseSidedPieces("er1r2r3") |-> res0: (Char, List[Char]) = (e,List(1, 2, 3))
```